# Validating the schema of a database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I have an application that reads from an SQL Server CE 4.0 database file.

The user has the option on startup to choose a database. Each database has the same schema, but different data.

Given that I want to ensure that they dont use an invalid database (or point the app at a word file or something), Is it possible to validate the schema of a selected database?

In the past I have used ADO.net to check that each column in each table exists but this seems dreadfully silly when entity framework is there. surely there must be something in EF that performs this, but I cant find it.

*I am looking for an answer more sophsticated than "Run a query and if it fails then the database is invalid" as there could be many other reasons why such a query would fail*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality in EF to do this.

You can use my SQL CE Scripting API, available via NuGet http://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.SqlCeScripting/

First use

```
DataSet GetSchemaDataSet(GetAllTableNames());
```

And save it and add to your app.

Then use

```
DataSet GetSchemaDataSet(GetAllTableNames());
```

on the loaded database

Then compare the two DataSets

```
DataSet dsDifferences = new Dataset();
dsOriginal.Merge(dsChanged);
dsDifferences = dsOriginal.GetChanges();
```

(If dsDifferences has tables with rows, then there were differences)

My library also has a method DetermineVersion(string fileName) to check if the file appears to be a valid SQLCE file.